# Express.js Router Middleware issues

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = (app) ->
  app.use '/v1', isValid, router

router.post '/users/:id/authentications', (req, res, next) ->
  obj = _.pick(req.body, 'provider', 'uid', 'oauth_token',
                'oauth_token_secret', 'nickname')

  unless _.isEmpty(obj)

    _.extend(obj, { user_id: req.params.id })

    sqs.sendMessage
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify obj
      QueueUrl: sqsQueueURLs['authentications']
    , (err, data) ->
      if err
        log err
        res.status(422)
        res.json({ 'message': 'Unprocessable Entity' })
      else
        res.status(201)
        res.json({ 'status': 'OK' })

isValid = (req, res, next) ->
  apiKey = req.headers['api-key']

  if not apiKey
    res.status(401)
    res.json { 'message': 'API Key is missing from request' }
  else
    next()
```

When I do a POST to the `/users/:id/authentications` endpoint, my app is returning a HTTP status code of 404 when I introduced the middleware. I've probably set it up wrong, but can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: Did you try two separate `app.use`s (e.g. `app.use '/v1', isValid` then `app.use '/v1', router`) instead of one? I don't recall if Express supports multiple middleware arguments like that for `app.use`.

Comment: Are you sending the request to `/users/:id/authentications` or `/v1/users/:id/authentications`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth `/v1/users/:id/authentications`